# how to get id of next p element?

Tags: jquery

I want to get ID of a next p tag.

HTML:

```
 <h1>
    <span class=" edit">
    <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    <a id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
    </span>
</h1>
<p class="getty" id="1" href="#">One</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span.edit > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).next("p").attr('id');
    alert(x);

});
```

It is giving nothing in alert. Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`p` element is next sibling of clicked anchors closest parent `h1` element. You need to traverse to parent `h1` element and then use `.next()` selector to target it:

```js
$(function(){
$('span.edit > a').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var x = $(this).closest('h1').next("p").attr('id');;
 alert(x);
});});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>
<span class=" edit">
<a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
<a id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>abc</a>
</span>
</h1>
<p class="getty" id="1" href="#">One</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`p` is the next of the parent of the clicked `a`, `.closest` will get you to the *closest parent spa*n tag.

```
$(this).closest("h1").next("p")[0].id;
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('span.edit > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).parent("span").next("p")[0].id;
    alert(x);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class=" edit">
<a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
<a id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>ICON</a>
</span>
<p class="getty" id="1" href="#">One</p>
```

Comment: @Aashi check the edited answer, working fine now. If it solves your problem please upbote and mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used `closest` to reach `h1` tag and then fetched the `<p>` tag which is next to it. And then grabbed its `id`

```js
$('span.edit > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).closest("h1").next("p").attr('id');
    alert(x);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h1>
    <span class=" edit">
    <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    <a id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Click Me</a>
    </span>
</h1>
<p class="getty" id="1" href="#">One</p>
```